# VSCode - code completion depending on a cursor position

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to develop an vs code extension by using its javascript apis.

i have a .hocon file (https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md) the file is fairly complex and i would like to create an autocomplete feature.

My problem:

1] I have a dictionary file, its a simple text file for sake of example lets assume its toml/csv something easy to parse

```
[ips]
x.x.x.x
y.y.y.y
some.ipv6

[actions]
someString1
someString2
```

2] the hocon file contains two arrays

```
Ips: [

]

Actions: [

]
```

When a user places a cursor inside the Ips array, i want to show standard code-completion pop up window which will contain list of ips from the dictionary file, but won't contain a single record from the actions block.

My question is: I looked at the vs code documentation and I feel like this cannot be solved by a simple vscode extension, but I should use some language server?  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to be able to parse your file to decide based on the cursor position what kind of autocomplete provider you want to invoke. No need for a language server, the extension itself could still do that logic.